# Redirect VS debugger to a specific connection

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, routing

I need my visual studio debugger to use my ethernet cable connection instead of wireless.

I already tried [ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) but it seems this solution doesn't work with windows7-64 bits

Do you guys know a workaround for this?

- I have added routes  through command line

  `route -p add <host-needed> mask <mask-address> <ip-address> metric 20 IF 13`

assumming `13` is the number shown in `route print` for my ethernet cable connection.

**EDIT:** I added route print

```
ILista de interfaces
 15...e0 06 e6 0b aa c9 ......Adaptador de red Broadcom 802.11n
 13...dc 0e a1 ea 46 9c ......Atheros AR8152/8158 PCI-E Fast Ethernet Controller (NDIS 6.20)
 11...64 27 37 cd 07 df ......Dispositivo Bluetooth (Red de  rea personal)
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 21...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Adaptador ISATAP de Microsoft
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Adaptador 6to4 de Microsoft
 20...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Adaptador ISATAP de Microsoft #3


===========================================================================

IPv4 Tabla de enrutamiento
===========================================================================
Rutas activas:
Destino de red        M scara de red   Puerta de enlace   Interfaz  M‚trica
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.39.1.1    10.39.100.130    276
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.103     25
         10.1.0.0      255.255.0.0        10.39.1.1    10.39.100.130     40
        10.39.0.0      255.255.0.0      En v¡nculo     10.39.100.130    276
    10.39.100.130  255.255.255.255      En v¡nculo     10.39.100.130    276
    10.39.255.255  255.255.255.255      En v¡nculo     10.39.100.130    276
       10.250.0.0      255.255.0.0        10.39.1.1    10.39.100.130     40
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0      En v¡nculo         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255      En v¡nculo         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      En v¡nculo         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0      En v¡nculo     192.168.1.103    281
    192.168.1.103  255.255.255.255      En v¡nculo     192.168.1.103    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255      En v¡nculo     192.168.1.103    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      En v¡nculo         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      En v¡nculo     10.39.100.130    276
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0      En v¡nculo     192.168.1.103    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      En v¡nculo         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      En v¡nculo     10.39.100.130    276
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255      En v¡nculo     192.168.1.103    281
===========================================================================
Rutas persistentes:
  Direcci¢n de red  M scara de red  Direcci¢n de puerta de enlace  M‚trica
         10.1.0.0      255.255.0.0        10.39.1.1      20
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0        10.39.1.1  Predeterminada 
       10.250.0.0      255.255.0.0        10.39.1.1      20
===========================================================================

IPv6 Tabla de enrutamiento
===========================================================================
Rutas activas:
 Cuando destino de red m‚trica      Puerta de enlace
 16     58 ::/0                     En v¡nculo
  1    306 ::1/128                  En v¡nculo
 16     58 2001::/32                En v¡nculo
 16    306 2001:0:9d38:6ab8:10c7:d95:4596:b971/128
                                    En v¡nculo
 13    276 fe80::/64                En v¡nculo
 15    281 fe80::/64                En v¡nculo
 16    306 fe80::/64                En v¡nculo
 16    306 fe80::10c7:d95:4596:b971/128
                                    En v¡nculo
 15    281 fe80::4891:2607:7764:7871/128
                                    En v¡nculo
 13    276 fe80::8dea:826a:c280:8732/128
                                    En v¡nculo
  1    306 ff00::/8                 En v¡nculo
 16    306 ff00::/8                 En v¡nculo
 13    276 ff00::/8                 En v¡nculo
 15    281 ff00::/8                 En v¡nculo
===========================================================================
Rutas persistentes:
  Ninguno
```

Hope you can help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: does the host exist on a network that already has a route to it? if so, the lowest metric will win. can you please post your whole route print, so we can look it over? also your interface should never be 13. Interface is usually expressed as an IP address. are you sure you're not confusing it with Metric?

Comment: @FrankThomas   i edited my post with `route print` output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the IP i was trying to reach had the exact same *alias* *name* than another one i was once connected at another place with other DNS's.

I can't quite figure out **why** was this happening since my hosts file was clean, but after I added the ip address in it, the problem was solved.